# I want to add some panels inside main panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I press the button to add, it adds only 1 panel inside the main panel.
I declared x and z at the top of the class.
the panel creates 1 text box and 1 button to delete the panel.

```
       Dim y, i As Integer
        If mainpanel.ToolTip.ToString() <> "" Then
            y = Convert.ToInt32(mainpanel.ToolTip.ToString())
        Else
            y = 1
            x = 1
        End If
    
        If y > 1 Then
            x = y
            For i = 1 To y - 1
                Dim pan As Panel = New Panel()
                Dim tb As TextBox = New TextBox()
                Dim but As Button = New Button()
                z = i + 1
                pan.ID = "panel" + z.ToString()
                tb.ID = "tb" + z.ToString()
                but.ID = "but" + z.ToString()
                mainpanel.Controls.Add(pan)
                pan.Controls.Add(tb)
                pan.Controls.Add(but)
    
            Next
            x = I
        End If
```

```
  Private Sub add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles add.Click
        Dim z As Integer
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim pan As Panel = New Panel()
        Dim tb As TextBox = New TextBox()
        Dim but As Button = New Button()
        z = x + 1
        pan.ID = "panel" + z.ToString()
        tb.ID = "tb" + z.ToString()
        but.ID = "but" + z.ToString()
        mainpanel.Controls.Add(pan)
        pan.Controls.Add(tb)
        pan.Controls.Add(but)
        x = z
        mainpanel.ToolTip = z.ToString()
    End Sub
```

Comment: surely you need a loop in your add_Click code?

Comment: Are you sure the x and z variables declared in add_click aren’t supposed to declared with a higher scope?  Pretty sure you’re re-creating the same panel on every click